# CAGradient not showing when locations are <0 or >1

Tags: swift, uilabel, gradient, cagradientlayer

I am trying to make a label with an animated gradient as its colour. I can get a static gradient just fine. I was playing around with animated gradients in a view with the intention of using a mask but that isn't happy with our custom label (although I think I've just realised why it wasn't working... I am thinking the solution I am currently working on is cleaner than a view). I did manage to get a nice seamless look using positions [-2, -1, 0, 1] and then animating to [0, 1, 2, 3].

Fast forward to where I started creating a label and it using the same gradient and passing setting that gradient as a color via the following extension methods:

```swift
extension UIColor {    
    convenience init(layer: CALayer) {
        let ctx = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: layer.bounds.size)
        let img = ctx.image { layer.render(in: $0.cgContext) }
        self.init(patternImage: img)
    }
}
```

It does not show. I compared it to what I had with my static gradient label and the only difference was the fact that I added positions (and of course the animation). I decided not to call the `animate` function which starts the animation and it was still invisible. I then commented out the position and all of a sudden it became visible. I then attempted to put the positions back and get rid of the negatives and values above 1 and it was visible. I then wondered if it was only outside the animation that it didn't like numbers outside [0,1] and the moment I start the animation it's gone again. made the positions inside the animation inside [0,1] and even then the animation isn't happy.

Here is my label class:

```swift
class AnimatedGradientLabel: BaseLabel {
    private let startColor: UIColor = Color.gradientOrange
    private let endColor: UIColor = Color.gradientPink
    private let duration: CFTimeInterval = 4.0
    private let repeatCount: Float = Float.infinity
    var font: Font = Font.regularText

    private lazy var gradient: CAGradientLayer = {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.colors = [
//            startColor.cgColor,
//            endColor.cgColor,
            startColor.cgColor,
            endColor.cgColor
        ]

        gradientLayer.locations = [
//            -2, -1, 0, 1 // not happy
//            0, 0, 0, 1 // happy provided I don't call animate()
            0, 1 // happy provided I don't call animate()
        ] as [NSNumber]

        return gradientLayer
    }()

    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            gradient.frame = bounds
            textColor = UIColor(layer: gradient)
        }
    }

    override func style() {
        super.style()
        font = Font.header
    }

    func animate() {
        gradient.colors = [
            endColor.cgColor,
            startColor.cgColor,
            endColor.cgColor,
            startColor.cgColor
        ]

        let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
        anim.fromValue = [-2, -1, 0, 1]
        anim.toValue = [0, 1, 2, 3]

        anim.duration = duration
        anim.repeatCount = repeatCount
        anim.fillMode = .forwards
        anim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        gradient.removeAllAnimations()
        gradient.add(anim, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions, please I would really appreciate it

EDIT:
Animation does set up there are only two colours, and is happy with both negative numbers and numbers above 1, but I noticed it doesn't animate.

EDIT2:
Weirdly Just got it working with multiple colours. Not entirely sure what I was doing wrong initially. What I did also notice is the reason its not animating. That UIColor convenience initializer makes a pattern out of the gradient. It doesn't use the gradient as is. DOH! Okay looks like I might need to go back to the drawing board

Comment: According t the documentation on locations: `The gradient stops are specified as values between 0 and 1. The values must be monotonically increasing`

Comment: @Larme, Thats what the documentation says ,yes, although you can go out of that range to be out of the visible area (which did work when i was testing in the view). What i understand about monotonically increasing is it cannot be  1, 0.5, 0 or 0, 1, 0.5. (makes sense because you are defining the positions from of the colours in your colour array from index 0 to n). 

Im back to fiddling around with the view layer and masking. See if I can make any progress there :)

Comment: Update, got it to work. Its does feel a little hacky, but what I had to do was inside our BaseLabel I added a gradient property. Inside it's`willSet` I first remove the current gradientLayer from its superview (if there is one) then if the `newValue` isn't `nil` I add I add it as a sublayer with `layer.addSublayer(newValue!)` then set its frame to `bounds`. I also needed to add a didSet for the `bounds` so that when `bounds` is updated it updates the gradients bounds. From there I just set up my custom label, set up the gradient and set property and deal with animation  in the custom label :)